# gradle plugins : com.android.application source code

Tags: android, plugins, gradle

Where can I find the source code of the  plugin "com.android.application"?
I have tried to find in [here](https://android.googlesource.com).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The source for `com.android.application` plugin is at:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/build/+/master/gradle/src/main/groovy/com/android/build/gradle/AppPlugin.groovy

The plugin name comes from this properties file:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/master/build-system/gradle/src/main/resources/META-INF/gradle-plugins/com.android.application.properties

and its contents point to the class implementing it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer,but I still can not find it.Actually the plugins "com.android.application" may created by google.So I don‘t think source is hosted on 
https://github.com/gradle/

Comment: I apologize! Looks like *I* need a less in basic comprehension :) Updated my answer

Comment: Thank you for your help very much.